# How can I define this generic class to return this kind of generic object?

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic class as follows:

```
class Holder<T>{  
    int type;  
    T value;  
}
```

I have a class with method as follows:

```
class SomeClass<T> {  
T insideValue;

??? process();  

}
```

I need from process to return a `Holder<T>`. How can I do this? What do I need to change in order to work? I think that if I did:
`class SomeClass<Holder<T>> {` it would be the same as `class Holder<T>` right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very simply:

```
Holder<T> process();
```

Closed generic types can be used just like other types (except at runtime).

Comment: So the class will still be `class SomeClass<T>`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this,

```
Holder<T> process(){

}
```